# Unable to list the LDAP groups in Hashicorp vault, along with the policy attached to it

Tags: python-3.x, hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp

I want to list LDAP groups in Hashicorp vault, along with the policy which is attached with those LDAP groups in python code. I am able to list all the LDAP groups but not able to get the commands to list the policy along with it.

Answer (score 1):

`vault list auth/ldap/groups` will list each of the LDAP group names. As mentioned in the previous answer though, the resulting list of groups would need to be iterated over, as the group list endpoint returns only group names, not policies with the group names. `vault read auth/ldap/groups/group_name` would return the attached policies along with other attributes.

List: https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/auth/ldap#list-ldap-groups

Read: https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/auth/ldap#read-ldap-group

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate for all listed groups to get the policy information. Something like done in the following Bash script:

```
for g in $(curl --silent --header "X-Vault-Token: VAULT-TOKEN" --request LIST https://VAULT-SERVER/v1/identity/group/name | jq --raw-output .data.keys[])
do
    echo -n "$g => "
    curl --silent --header "X-Vault-Token: VAULT-TOKEN" --request GET https://VAULT-SERVER/v1/identity/group/name/$g | jq --raw-output .data.policies[]
done
```